# Retrieving the Environment Starting Program for a Local Server user?

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2003

I am using a [vbscript](http://sydiproject.com/) to retrieve local user account details.  This script uses the [Win32_Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28VS.85%29.aspx) .

An excerpt from that script:

```
If (bWMILocalAccounts) Then
    ReportProgress " Gathering local users"
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Description, Name, FullName, LocalAccount from Win32_UserAccount Where Domain='" & strComputerSystem_Name & "'",,48)
    Set objDbrLocalAccounts = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
    objDbrLocalAccounts.Fields.Append "Description", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
    objDbrLocalAccounts.Fields.Append "UserName", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
```

Is it possible to read the 'Environment -> Starting Program' path?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info you're looking for is coming from ADSI, so I searched a bit and found this [link](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/scripting/scripting-server-based-computing-terminal-services-attributes-active-directory-user-objects.html) on virtualizationadmin.com. It provides a nice table showing which fields in the Active Directory Users and Computers tab match their attribute for use in a script (batch, vbs, etc.).

With that info in hand, activexperts.com [gives a great sample VBScript](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/tsaccounts/#ReadTSEEnv.htm) to display this info, as copied here, which you can work into your script.

```
Set objUser = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://cn=MyerKen,ou=Management,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

intConnectClientDrivesAtLogon = objUser.ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon
intConnectClientPrintersAtLogon = objUser.ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon
intDefaultToMainPrinter = objUser.DefaultToMainPrinter
strTerminalServicesInitialProgram = objUser.TerminalServicesInitialProgram
strTerminalServicesWorkDirectory = objUser.TerminalServicesWorkDirectory

WScript.echo "ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon: " & intConnectClientDrivesAtLogon
WScript.echo "ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon: " & _
    intConnectClientPrintersAtLogon
WScript.echo "DefaultToMainPrinter: " & intDefaultToMainPrinter
WScript.echo "TerminalServicesInitialProgram: " & _
    strTerminalServicesInitialProgram 
WScript.echo "TerminalServicesWorkDirectory: " & _
    strTerminalServicesWorkDirectory
```